# How to use bulk upsert in a loop?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

The fields that I have in Mongoldb are; 
id, website_url, status.

I need to find the website_url and update its status to 3 and add a new field called err_desc.

I have a list of website_urls, its status and its err_desc.

Below is my code.

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 9000)
db1 = client['Company_Website_Crawl']
collection1 = db1['All']
posts1 = collection1.posts
bulk = posts1.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
website_url = ["http://www.example.com","http://example2.com/"]
err_desc = ["error1","error2"]
for i in website_url:
    parsed_uri = urlparse(i)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    final_url = domain
    final_url_strip = domain.rstrip("/")
    print i,final_url,final_url_strip,"\n"
    try:
        k = bulk.find({'website_url':i}).upsert().update({'$push':{'err_desc':err_desc,'status':3}})
        k = bulk.execute()
        print k
    except Exception as e:
        print "fail"
        print e
```

**Error**

> fail batch op errors occurred
>
> fail Bulk operations can only be executed once.

Initially I used

```
k =  posts1.update({'website_url':final_url_strip},{'$set':{'err_desc':err_desc,'status':3}},multi=True)
```

It was too slow for 5M records. So I wanted to use bulk update option. Kindly help me to use bulk upsert for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you need to re-initialize the batch writes operation after calling [`execute()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/bulk.html#pymongo.bulk.BulkOperationBuilder.execute). But the thing is, you are doing it wrong. In you case, you need to call `execute` at the end of the for loop like this:

```
from itertools import count


ct = count()

for url in website_url:
    ...
    try:
        bulk.find({'website_url':i}).upsert().update({'$push':{'err_desc':err_desc,'status':3}})
        val = next(ct)
    except Exception as e:
        ...
if val > 0:
    bulk.execute()
```

Also note that `Bulk()` is now deprecated and replaced with [`bulkwrite`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write)

Comment: Thanks @S.M.Styvane. I have two clarifications. 1. Also note that Bulk() is now deprecated and replaced with bulk write ( I couldn't understand where you are referring to.) 2. pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred is the error I come across.

Comment: Take a look at the description of bulkwrite in the 3.2 release note [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#mongo-shell-and-crud-api)

Comment: Thanks @S.M.Styvane. It worked. Can you please clear me another doubt. Is it possible to find if any records fail. For example, if the value of **i** is not found in the database, I need to substitute another value and try finding the record and make changes. Is it possible and if so, how can I handle ?